# What is the equivalent of StyleBundle and ScriptBundle in node.js/expressjs/ejs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working on a project for my web applications course. One of the requirements for the project is to use the MEAN stack (mongo, express, angular, node). I also use EJS as the view engine.

I'm new to node, mongo and express, but I do have a lot of experience with ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI.

In ASP.NET MVC there's a library called `System.Web.Optimization` containing `StyleBundle` and `ScriptBundle` classes. One can create a bundle and add stylesheets/scripts to it, then link it to the view with `Scripts.Render("path/to/bundle")` (or `Styles.Render(...)`), which, depending on the app's configuration, would be replaced with either links to every file in the bundle, or a single link to a server-generated file containing the contents of all files inside that bundle, minified.

Is there an equivalent of this functionality in node/express/EJS? For the project I'm not really interested in the auto-minification functionality (but it could be good to know), but more in the bundling mechanism.